# Scan a single file using MSSE

Tags: windows, ms-security-essentials

I would like to be able to scan a single file using the command prompt on my Windows PC. I am using MSSE.

The documents show that it supports the command line interface but, it would appear as if it only supports scanning by system.

I want it to scan a single file, by passing a command like

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\MpCmdRun.exe %File%
```

How is this possible ? Or is it just not possible as of version 4?